# Sequentially execute observables and emit one result

Tags: rxjs, observable, sequential

I have an array of observables which I'm executing in parallel using:

```
let observables: Observable<any>[]

Observable.forkJoin(observables)
```

This works perfectly, however, I need to execute the array of observables sequentially, and only emit one result if the last observable has been completed. That's when I tried to use

```
Observable.concat(observables)
```

But this returns multiple results, and not only one - combined - result which I get when using forkJoin. So I actually need a combination of the two.

I've tried to use the reduce functionality to execute them sequentially, like this:

```
return observables.reduce((previous, current) => {
  return previous.flatMap(() => current);
}, Observable.empty());
```

But with this solution the observables are not executed at all.

Comment: Your reduce-code would work if you didn't use empty() as the first one. Use Observable.of(null), for example. You need to start the chain by emitting one event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that your `observables` emit **singular** values, **not arrays**, you could rework your current approach to something like:

```
return Observable.concat(...observables).reduce((acc, current) => [...acc, current], []);
```

or even shorter:

```
return Observable.concat(...observables).toArray();
```

In the case that they emit **array** values, you could do the following:

```
const source = Observable.concat(...observables).flatMap(list => list).toArray();
```

Answer (score 9):

As [Jota.Toledo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359370/8712609) or [Mateusz Witkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359003/8712609) showed in their answers, with the **new syntax of RxJS** you can do:

```
return concat(...observables).pipe(toArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can you use `toArray()` operator:

```
Observable.concat(observables).toArray().subscribe()
```

As stated in RxJS documentation: it creates "an observable sequence containing a single element with a list containing all the elements of the source sequence".

Comment: @TomvanBrienen no. It transorms an observable of elements into an observable of array of elements. The unique array emittied by the result observable contains all the elements emitted by the source observable.

Comment: should be `Observable.concat(...observables).toArray().subscribe()`

Comment: @pixelbits You don't need to unwrap the array for `concat`. Both will work.

Comment: @martin No, there is a difference.  One emits an array of observables. The other emits an observable of an array.

Comment: @pixelbits I really doubt it. See this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/concat.ts#L9-L16 and this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/concat.ts#L111. Otherwise give me a demo where `concat` behaves differently when used like `concat([a, b, c])` and `concat(...[a, b, c])`.

Comment: @martin you're referring to the simple case of an observable stream of values. In the ops example, the source is an array of observables. You should try it yourself:)